# List request not working (Mongoose in Node.js with Typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am using mongoose in Nodejs with typescript. In a list request, I have the following code:

```
async list(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)
{
    try {
        let list: ListInterface[] = []
        await RequestModel.find().then(requests =>
        {
            requests.map(async request =>
            {
                const client = await Client.findById(request.cliente)
                const seller = await Seller.findById(request.vendedor)
                const company = await Company.findById(request.representada)
                const tmp =
                {
                    id: request._id,
                    data: request.data,
                    cliente: String(client?.nome_fantasia),
                    vendedor: String(seller?.nome),
                    representada: String(company?.nome_fantasia),
                    tipo: request.tipo,
                    status: request.status
                }
                list.push(tmp)
                console.log(tmp)
            })
        })
        console.log(list)
        return res.json(list)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

When I make the request in Insomnia, I receive an empty array (both in the terminal -- because of `console.log(list)` -- and on Insomnia's preview): `[]`. In the terminal, as a result of the `console.log(tmp)` command, I receive the proper data.

I have already tried to declare the list as something like `const list = request.map(...)`, but it gives me `[Promise<Pending>, Promise<Pending>]` in the terminal and `[{}, {}]` in Insomnia. I could not repeat exactly the same code of this test, but I remember those results.

I'm not even sure about which technology I'm misusing. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` function returns a list of promises, so have to wait for them before sending back the response.

```js
async list(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)
{
    try {
        let list: ListInterface[] = []
        const requests = await RequestModel.find()
        
        // collect all promises from the loop
        const promises = requests.map(async request =>
        {
            const client = await Client.findById(request.cliente)
            const seller = await Seller.findById(request.vendedor)
            const company = await Company.findById(request.representada)
            const tmp =
            {
                id: request._id,
                data: request.data,
                cliente: String(client?.nome_fantasia),
                vendedor: String(seller?.nome),
                representada: String(company?.nome_fantasia),
                tipo: request.tipo,
                status: request.status
            }
            list.push(tmp)
            console.log(tmp)
        })
        
        // wait for all promises to complete
        await Promise.all(promises)
        
        console.log(list)
        return res.json(list)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```